# Checking if a word appears a column with space delimited words

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table

**EMP TABLE**

```
+--+----+--------------+
|ID|Name|Address       |
+--+----+--------------+
|1 |Jack|Street  Road  |
+--+----+--------------+
|2 |Jill|Park Side Lane|
+--+----+--------------+
```

I Want to Where clause on each word of address how can it be possible?

I am using a Select Query Like

```
SELECT *
FROM emp 
WHERE
SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, " " ,1 ) = ?
OR
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, " " ,2 ) , " " , -1) = ?
OR
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, " " ,3 ) , " " , -1) = ?;
```

**But What if i have more that 3 words in my address field.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL has a neat function to search for a string inside a list defined as a string called `FIND_IN_SET`. Unfortunately, it only works with comma-delimited values, but that can be worked around with some `REPLACE` trickery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   emp 
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(?, REPLACE (address, ' ', ',')) > 0
```