# MySQL - Search for space separated keywords.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a private project of mine, and I've been stuck here for a while. I have a MySQL database that has a table called "articles" which contains a column called "article_tags" Now say one of my PHP variables is holding something like "dwayne johnson arguing". I basically want to go into my database and look for any instances of these space separated keywords and grab that whole row if any one of the keywords occur. In my database, the "article_tags" column is holding these keywords as "arguing cars toys word word word" Since the keyword "arguing" was in there, I need to fetch that whole row.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: explode your string and build a like query in loop with wild cards `%`

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has a method called [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), which does what you want, but only on comma separated strings:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("search_value", tags)
```

However, I'm pretty sure that it will not be able to efficiently use an index in this case, so it might be very slow for large record sets.

If you can't change the separator for some reason and you know that your tags will not contain either spaces or commas, then you could probably do this:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET("search_value", REPLACE(tags, " ", ","))
```

`find_in_set` returns an integer that indicates where in the string the match was found. So it'll return '2' for `find_in_set('b', 'a,b,c')`. If it returns 0, the string was not found. If you're using it in a `WHERE` statement, do this: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET("search_value", tags) > 0`.

<sup>As you might know, the most sane way to do tagging in MySQL is probably to save the tags to a separate table and use a `one-to-many` or `many-to-many` relationship. You'll not be bound to a specific separator and you can use indexes to speed up searches.</sup>

Comment: The REPLACE workaround is also proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21187323/1066234 - Question is if the query is still performant.

Comment: No, not like this (not even with 8 years of development!) but in a scenario where you truly can't change your data, you could probably use `REPLACE()` to turn the space separated string into a JSON array and [then index that with a functional index](https://planetscale.com/blog/indexing-json-in-mysql#functional-indexes)—but again, it's much better to tag in a separate table (or a real JSON type column + index)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$str = "dwayne johnson arguing";
$arr_words = explode(" ", $str);
foreach($arr_words as $word)
{
    $word = trim($word);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `article_tags` LIKE '%$word%'";

    // RUN SQL HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE
  LOWER(`text`) REGEXP '\b(the|quick|fox)\b'
```

i wish it help you my friend

Answer (score -1):

You can use like operator

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE tag like %dwayne% OR like %arguing%"
```